# Display many thousand images in three.js

Tags: three.js

I have up to 200'000 individual images in a scene (done with sprites, so far). I want to look at these sprites, and when I fly around they should always face the camera (as sprites do).
My question is: How can I achieve the best performance WebGL-wise? Are Sprites with useScreenCoordinates:false rendered as with GL_POINT?
At the moment the fps drops with very low image counts already. I'm using mipmapping and sprites so far. And since they need to turn around to face me I didn't want to use BufferGeometry..

I'd highly appreciate some ideas and inputs :) Thanks!

PS: Point of it all is that you can "fly" through 200'000 images and stop/select the ones you figure to be interesting

Comment: Is it 200,000 different images? Or are there all the same one?

Comment: Oh, hey. I coded something now. Different images. What I did so far is: ParticleSystem (GL_POINT) with BufferGeometry for further away images, asynchronous loading of images after a nearest neighbour search (kd-tree in my case) + view frustum culling. I used sprites for the particles, like a fake image sort of :)
But now I'm having trouble with the kd-tree. A 200'000 points array of THREE.Vector3() is up to ~10MB in size, while a Float32Array with 200'000*3 length is ~1.5 MB. But I can't finda nearest neighbour search for such an attribute-like data structure ^^ Maybe gotta code my own :(

Comment: If you have any further optimization ideas please tell me! I'm also in the IRC btw: Doidel ^^

Comment: I wrote my own in-place quicksearch + kdtree, I now run 200k+ pointsprites with 60 FPS and 2MB memory usage ^^ mrdoob, can you tell me how I then can request a contribution of the code to the three.js project?

Comment: Nice! Would like to see :) For contributing you need an account on github, fork the three.js repo, checkout the dev branch, commit your contribution, push to your origin and do a Pull Request.

Comment: Hmm I'll give my best.. Don't quite know where to put it, I trust in you to correct whatever I mess up ^^

Comment: wow the hardest part is committing this stuff to github.. and you get no help in IRC nor anywhere else, about to give up...

Comment: ye ok, giving up. I forked and pushed and pulled and grabbed and whatever, and I want to code and don't want to spend hours figuring out github. I'll maybe release the source somewhere else..

Comment: Yep. Learning git/github takes some effort.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Used tons of techniques and stuff, I'll be writing about it on http://blogs.fhnw.ch/threejs/ once I got it all working

Comment: do you have a link to your finished site? Or did you ever create a Pull Request on GitHub? It looks like you forked three.js but never pushed commits to your fork, and the blog notes never completed. If you have a live link to the site, or a copy of the old code, I'd love to see it!

Answer (score 2):

My team needed to accomplish this too, and sadly Doidel's notes trail off before the project is completed. We developed [PixPlot](https://github.com/YaleDHLab/pix-plot), a three.js visualization layer for images:

[image]

I put together a blog post outlining the details here: http://douglasduhaime.com/posts/visualizing-tsne-maps-with-three-js.html

In short, if others face this problem, you'll want to create one geometry (ideally) with one large image atlas (a single jpg of size 2048px by 2048px containing lots of smaller images) serving as the texture for the geometry. Add vertices, faces, and vertexUV's for each of the little images to display, and pull each image from the atlas texture.